# Such a broken Ruby loop

Tags: ruby

I'm using Sonic Pi on Mac and the following code with a while loop just goes right over what I want the condition to be.

```
cut = 0
until cut >= 110 do
    cue :foo
    4.times do |i|
      use_random_seed 667
      16.times do
        use_synth :tb303
        play chord(:e3, :minor).choose, attack: 0, release: 0.1, cutoff: cut + i * 10
        sleep 0.125
        cut += 1
        puts cut
      end
    end
    cue :bar
    32.times do |i|
      use_synth :tb303
      play chord(:a3, :minor).choose, attack: 0, release: 0.05, cutoff: cut + i, res: rrand(0.9, 0.95)
      sleep 0.125
      cut += 1
      puts cut
    end
  end
```

I need so much help lol

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. (As you can probably guess from the lack of answers.) *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Also, please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified *example* that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the Code, I should see the *exact same problem* you see.

Comment: As a corrolary to both being *minimal* and being *reproducible*, your example should ideally work by simply copy&pasting it without having to jump through any extra hoops like having to install third-party libraries. If the problem is actually specifically with interacting with a third-party library, then this should be clearly indicated (at least in the tags and in the question), and the specific flavor, version, build, branch, etc. of the library should be clearly identified.

Comment: In your case, your code example requires me to install Sonic Pi to run it, but you never say which version you use, so it is impossible to tell whether any problem I see or any solution I find is related to the version that you are using. However, while it is not fully clear from your question what the actual problem is, it looks like it doesn't actually have anything to do with Sonic Pi (in the title, you talk about loops, and loops are a Ruby language construct that cannot be changed by a library), so your example should be written in such a way that Sonic Pi is not required.

Answer (score 2):

So, after install Sonic Pi 3.1.0 (which I hope is the same version you are using), I was able to test your code, and I get an `ArgumentError` exception (which I hope is the same exception you are getting):

```
Runtime Error: [buffer 0, line 8] - RuntimeError
Thread death!
 Value of opt :cutoff must be a value less than or equal to 130, got 131.
```

which points to this line:

> ```rb
> play chord(:e3, :minor).choose, attack: 0, release: 0.1, cutoff: cut + i * 10
> ```

I think the error message is pretty clear: you need to make sure that `cut + i * 10` never exceeds 130. The same obviously also applies to this line:

> ```rb
> play chord(:a3, :minor).choose, attack: 0, release: 0.05, cutoff: cut + i, res: rrand(0.9, 0.95)
> ```

There are multiple ways of doing this. They all will have different musical effects.

## [`Enumerable#clamp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Comparable.html#method-i-clamp)

`Enumerable#clamp` allows you to "clamp" a value between two other values, in other words, the value will never go below the minum or above the maximum.

The most elegant way of doing that would be to use the second overload taking a [`Range`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html) argument:

```rb
play chord(:e3, :minor).choose, attack: 0, release: 0.1, cutoff: (cut + i * 10).clamp(..130)
```

Unfortunately, Sonic Pi 3.1.0 uses an older version of Ruby which doesn't support beginless range yet. Therefore, we use the first overload and pass the value of negative infinity explicitly:

```rb
play chord(:e3, :minor).choose, attack: 0, release: 0.1, cutoff: (cut + i * 10).clamp(-Float::Infinity, 130)
```

## [`Integer#%`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-25)

```rb
play chord(:e3, :minor).choose, attack: 0, release: 0.1, cutoff: (cut + i * 10) % 131
```

## Scaling

A third possible way would be to make sure that we scale the value appropriately, so that in the last iteration of the loop, it is exactly 130.

In the first line, `cut + i * 10` can go up to `189`. In the second line, `cut + i` can go up to `222`. Therefore, we need to scale the value by `130 ÷ 189` and `130 ÷ 222`, respectively, like this:

```rb
play chord(:e3, :minor).choose, attack: 0, release: 0.1, cutoff: (cut + i * 10) * 130.0 / 189
```

Comment: However, none work how I want them to.

Comment: Unfortunately, "none work how I want them to" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mre] (with emphasis on *minimal*).